# Replacing Field name with a report variable

Tags: reporting-services

For expression =Fields!FieldName.Value, I want to get FieldName value from a report variable. How do I replace this so that i can get =Fields!MyReportVariable.Value ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reference the variables collections

=Variables!MyReportVariable.Value